# Unregistered SOAP Client 3.0 on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, soap, soap-client

I've developed a Web Application (web site) using VS 2010 and VB.NET. I'm able to run the application successfully from VS. But when I Publish and upload it on my hosting server this error message occurs.

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7F017F97-9257-11D5-87EA-00B0D0BE6479} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I've downloaded the SOAP toolkit 3.0 and imported it in my application reference. here is my code:

```
Imports MSSOAPLib30


Dim objSoapClient As New SoapClient30             '=== Create an instance of SoapClient

            '=== Set Client Properties
            objSoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True

            '=== Retrieve KWMP web services WSDL
            Call objSoapClient.mssoapinit("https://example.com/ReferencePayment?WSDL", "ReferencePayment")
            '=== Set connection property to be over SSL
            objSoapClient.ConnectorProperty("UseSSL") = False

            '=== Now consume the web sevices according to KWMP Specification
            Dim output As String = objSoapClient.verifyTransaction(RCode, "00105952-129251")
```

**--Update--**
except the method above, I was thinking of using POST web method to consume the SOAP XML.
here is the xml request generated by WCF Test Client:

```
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" />
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <q1:verifyTransaction xmlns:q1="urn:Foo">
  <String_1 xsi:type="xsd:string">12345678901234567890</String_1>
  <String_2 xsi:type="xsd:string">00109902-129251</String_2>
</q1:verifyTransaction>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and I have method to consume the SOAP XML which returns Internal Server Error 500 !!!!! You think which part is wrong ?!

```
 Public Function ServiceCall(RefCode As String) As String
    Dim resultXml As String
    Dim wbrqst As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://modern.enbank.net/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL")
    Dim httpreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(wbrqst, HttpWebRequest)
    httpreq.Method = "POST"
    httpreq.ContentType = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    httpreq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://modern.enbank.net/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment")
    'httpreq.Headers.Add("<Action s:" + "ReferencePayment>")
    httpreq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
    httpreq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim requestStream As Stream = httpreq.GetRequestStream()
    Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>")
    sb.Append("<s:Body s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>")
    sb.Append("<q1:verifyTransaction xmlns:q1='urn:Foo'>")
    sb.Append("xml:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'")
    sb.Append("<verifyTransaction xmlns='urn:Foo'")
    sb.Append("<String_1 xsi:type='xsd:string'>12345678901234567890</String_1>")
    sb.Append("<String_2 xsi:type='xsd:String'>00109902-129251</String_2>")
    sb.Append("</q1:verifyTransaction> </s:Body></s:Envelope>")
    streamWriter.Write(sb.ToString())
    streamWriter.Close()
    Dim wr As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpreq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim srd As New StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream())
    resultXml = srd.ReadToEnd()
    Return resultXml

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with that tool, you may want to use the WCFTest Client, which should work with you soap message, thise can be found from within the VS2010 folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

Just add the service you want to open, it should then create a client proxy for you on the fly.

Update:

You may want to use add web reference and create a webservice project as part of a VS project.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for you answer. using your method I would be able to test the feedback from the server which I've been already able to do. The problem is when I upload my application on the web server (hosting server) it gives me that error message.

Comment: Does you webservice call any unmanaged resources, COM, Win32 api?

Comment: yes, I'm calling MSSOAPLib30 DLL which I added as COM reference

Comment: If your hosting externally, you may be in medium trust environment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617454/what-is-medium-trust-in-asp-net, and will not be able to run Win32 Api's

Comment: Lain, Please check my update on this post, you may have clue to help me. thanks

Comment: Just wondering if you have tried adding adding a web reference to your project and creating webservice project?

Comment: you maaaaade my day, thank you for the help. it works now. you re-post this as another answer to help other people. thank you again