# Accessing folder outside website's root folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, root, loadcontrol, virtual-path

I have a around 15 websites on a server, i have built a tool which is common across all the sites.

Now instead of keeping the same files inside individual site's folder, i decided to keep the folder common, and keep it outside the website's folder, so that i don't have to keep the files under all the sites.

But my problem is if the folder is outside the website's root folder, i am unable to access it, as `Server.MapPath` does not works.

I even tried to keep those files under a folder in one of the site's root, and access them like http://domain.com/folder/control.ascx but that too does not works. it throws error saying :`http:/domain.com/folder/control.ascx' is not a valid virtual path`

Can anyone help me about how could i access the files outside the root folder, or keeping it inside one the site's root folder.

Comment: Read about [Medium Trust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617454/what-is-medium-trust-in-asp-net) against Full Trust. Also here http://www.smarterasp.net/support/KB/a252/whats-difference-between-aspnet-full-trust-medium-trust.aspx

Comment: Hi @Steve can you tell me how can i define trust levels, because i have dedicated server for my websites. So i think i can go with this. So if i have full trust then can i do the above task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a virtual directory under your site that points to the common directory?

```
Server
  Sites
    Common - base directory is C:\sites\common\
    SiteA - base directory is C:\sites\siteA\
      common - virtual directory pointing to C:\sites\common
    SiteB - base directory is C:\sites\siteB\
      common - virtual directory pointing to C:\sites\common
```

Comment: Hi @Anderson, how can i create the directory outside my website as a virtual directory, because that directory won't be available in IIS for making it virtual, however i tried keeping that folder under one of the website and made it virtual, but that too didn't helped.

Comment: This was the easiest, fastest and safest solution thanks a lot @Anderson

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Trust Level of your whole site to Full Trust

Just open the `IIS Manager`, click on the root node and double click on `NET Trust Levels`. Here you can experiment with various Trust levels to see if your Server.MapPath allows cross site paths

[Here an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) with details on how to do it also with a command line